# Angular2 Router: Cannot find the outlet XOutlet to load YComponent

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm having trouble when using named router outlets on Angular2 2.1.2.

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot find the outlet XOutlet to load 'YComponent'

The error is pretty clear itself, but I'm stuck and can't find a way around it.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<router-outlet name="XOutlet"></router-outlet>
<!-- Main content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The Routes file:

```
{
    path: 'other', 
    component: OtherComponent, 
    children: [
        {
            path: 'list',
            component: YComponent,
            outlet: 'XOutlet'
        }
    ]
},
```

The link

```
 <a [routerLink]="['other', {outlets: {'XOutlet': 'list'}}]"><span>Other</span></a>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks

EDIT: Based on the comment by Oleg Barinov, the HTML provided is part of the base HTML, not from the OtherComponent HTML.

Comment: Is the provided HTML template is a template of `OtherComponent`?

Comment: No, the HTML is part of the base component, OtherComponent is meant to be rendered on the unnamed outlet and the YComponent is meant to be rendered on the XOutlet.

Comment: ok, so can you try to use `[routerLink]="['/', ...` instead

Comment: That made it work, but it's not how I wanted to work. I want to load the Y component when the URL is under /other, I should find another way. Thanks!

Comment: In this way you should add `<router-outlet>` directly to your OtherComponent template add add a child route without any 'outlet' property (so you can also remove second outlet from root)

Comment: Yes, that way I made it work before but I had issues with the CSS. I will work on that styling, it's the correct thing to do.

Comment: Ok, posted an answer for the original question )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<a [routerLink]="['/', {outlets: {'XOutlet': 'list'}}]"><span>Other</span></a>` for this kind of implementation.